# If n is a positive integer that is not square free

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Determine if the statement is, in general, true or false. Recall that a
universal statement is true if it is true for all possible cases while it is false if there is even one counterexample. Be prepared to prove that your answer is correct by supplying a proof or counterexample, whichever is appropriate.

If $n$ is a positive integer that is not square free then there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a\ne b\pmod n$. But so that $a^k\equiv b^k\pmod n$ for all $k>1$.

---

*Solution*:

Since $n$ is not a square free integer then $n=k(m^2)$.  Now, $a^k\equiv b^k\pmod n$ and $a^k\equiv b^k\pmod{m^2}$.  Thus, it is not necessary that $a\ne b\pmod n$.  Hence, if $n$ is a positive integer that is not square free then there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a\ne b\pmod n$.  But so that $a^k\equiv b^k\pmod n$ for all $k>1$.

Could you check it for me please?  Is it correct or not?

Answer (score 1):

"Thus it is not necessary that ..." is not a compelling argument. I suggest you exhibit explicitly $a=m$, $b=0$ and show that $a^k\equiv 0\equiv b^k\pmod{m^2}$ (and so also $a^k\equiv b^k\pmod n$) for all $k>1$. And of course we have $a\not\equiv b\pmod n$ (as $n\ge m^2>m>0$).